# JAVA classes com.adobe.xmp.* not found

Tags: java

I am not able to find the downloadable source code for the classes in :

```
com.adobe.xmp.*
```

along with all the dependencies....

Any place you can suggest?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: add xmp dependency to the classpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at

http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/xmptoolkit/

Answer (score 2):

Check with [Extensible Metadata Platform (XMP)](http://www.adobe.com/products/xmp/)

Answer (score 2):

Download [xmpcore-5.1.2.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/x/Downloadxmpcore512jar.htm). Add that as an external jar to your project.

It looks like all the code directly from Adobe is .cpp now. Java may no longer be supported.